# How to close a window post function call?

Tags: javascript

I have at the end of my user journey a popup modal saying 'Success! You may now return to X', which then triggers a function to 'confirm' the Step.. However, the user has to manually close the page and I would like it to close itself, perhaps on a short timer from when the 'confirmStep' function is called. However the only method I could find for this is Window.close(), which won't work as I don't ever call Window.open(). Does anyone have a suggestion for a way around this issue? Code attached below for context:

```
confirm() {
  this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
    message: this.t('tickets.stages.confirmation.simplified_confirm_reply'),
    onConfirm: () => this.confirmStep()
  })
```

Comment: You don't need to have used `window.open()` in order to use `window.close()`.

Comment: Don't close windows in the user's browser unless you are certain you opened the window. There may be other pages in the window's history that this would lose. This annoys the user.